# left primitive but not right primitive

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

There is a known example due to Bergman (goes back to 1963) of a ring which is left primitive but not right primitive. I am wondering if there is another (preferably simpler) example of such a ring!?

Answer (score 5):

see page 159 of [Ring Theory](http://books.google.nl/books?id=bd-DTiAX7uMC&pg=PA159), volume 1, by L.H. Rowen.

[image]

Comment: In the following works R. S. Irving, On the primitivity of certain Ore extensions (1979) http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01420415 and M. J. Crabb, J. Duncan and C. M. McGregor, On one-sided primitivity of Banach algebras (2010) http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091508000783 alternative/simpler examples are provided.